# What's wrong with the function multiplyTwoMatrices() in this C code for finding fibonacci using matrix multiplication?

Tags: c, matrix-multiplication, fibonacci

```
#include<stdio.h>

void multiplyTwoMatrices(int (*)[2], int[][2], int[][2]);
void copyMatrix(int[][2], int[][2]);
void powerAMatrix(int[][2], int[][2], int);

int main()
{
    int num;
    scanf("%d", &num);

    int i;
    for(i = -1; i <= num; i++)
    {
        printf("\n%d", fib(i));
    }
}

int fib(int num)
{
    if(num <= 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        int matrix[2][2] = {{1, 1}, {1, 0}};
        //int fibMatrix[2][2] = powerAMatrix(matrix[2][2], num);
        int fibMatrix[2][2];
        powerAMatrix(fibMatrix, matrix, num);
        return getFibNum(fibMatrix);
    }
}

void powerAMatrix(int fibMatrix[2][2], int matrix[2][2], int num)
{
    //fibMatrix = matrix;
    copyMatrix(fibMatrix, matrix);
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 1; i < num; i++)
    {
        //fibMatrix = fibMatrix * matrix;
        multiplyTwoMatrices(fibMatrix, fibMatrix, matrix);
    }
}

void copyMatrix(int destinationMatrix[2][2], int sourceMatrix[2][2])
{
    int i = 0; int j = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        for(j = 0; j < 2; j++)
            destinationMatrix[i][j] = sourceMatrix[i][j];
}

void multiplyTwoMatrices(int multipliedMatrix[2][2], int matrixA[2][2], int matrixB[2][2])
{

    int i = 0; int j = 0; int k = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        {
            multipliedMatrix[i][j] = 0;     //or just initialize it as a zero matrix.
            for(k = 0; k < 2; k++)
            {
                multipliedMatrix[i][j] += (matrixA[i][k] * matrixB[k][j]);
            }
        }
    }
                    //working alternative
    /*
    int x =  matrixA[0][0]*matrixB[0][0] + matrixA[0][1]*matrixB[1][0];
    int y =  matrixA[0][0]*matrixB[0][1] + matrixA[0][1]*matrixB[1][1];
    int z =  matrixA[1][0]*matrixB[0][0] + matrixA[1][1]*matrixB[1][0];
    int w =  matrixA[1][0]*matrixB[0][1] + matrixA[1][1]*matrixB[1][1];

    multipliedMatrix[0][0] = x;
    multipliedMatrix[0][1] = y;
    multipliedMatrix[1][0] = z;
    multipliedMatrix[1][1] = w;
    */
}

int getFibNum(int fibMatrix[2][2])
{
    return fibMatrix[0][1];
}
```

The function multiplyTwoMatrices() seems to work only if "working alternative" (code closed in comments inside this function) is used instead of the one used currently. I'm unable to understand what is going wrong with this code. A little help is appreciated.

Output expected: 0 0 1 1 2 3 5 8 ...

Output coming:   0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

while your multiplication function is correct, it doesn't work correctly when the destination is one of the operands; if it is, the operand is changed there while the calculation is underway.

Either require that `multipliedMatrix` is distinct from both `matrixA` and `matrixB` (that'd be preferred), or have a temporary matrix there and copy it into the result!

---

P.S. it would be much easier wrapping the matrix class into a struct:

```
struct intmatrix2x2 {
    int values[2][2];
};
```

this would make implicit copies when calling functions; and instead of `copyMatrix` you can say:

```
struct intmatrix2x2 b = a;
```

and your multiplication could read as

```
struct intmatrix2x2 multiply(struct intmatrix2x2 a, struct intmatrix2x2 b)
{
    struct intmatrix2x2 result;
    int i = 0; int j = 0; int k = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        {
            result.values[i][j] = 0;     //or just initialize it as a zero matrix.
            for(k = 0; k < 2; k++)
            {
                result.values[i][j] += a.values[i][k] * b.values[k][j]);
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

and you could use it as

```
struct intmatrix2x2 result = multiply(a, b);
```